# glTexGeni and glBindTexture

Tags: opengl

To call `glTexGeni()`, must I call the following first?

```
glBindTexture(texType, texId);
glEnable(texType);
```

Doing that will I set `glTexGeni()` to a desired texId?

Otherwise, what's the behaviour if I call `glTexGeni()` before `glBindTexture()`:

```
glTexGeni(...);
glBindTexture(texType, texId);
glEnable(texType);
```

Answer (score 1):

`glTexGeni()` does not deal with texture IDs. The texture IDs you use (indirectly) with `glBindTexture()` is created by `glGenTextures()`.

[This page](http://www.nullterminator.net/gltexture.html) has an example on how to use `glGenTextures()` and `glBindTexture()`.